# How to use docx npm package in production to save a file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docx, mern

I am generating a doc file using docx-template npm package in node js. and the file is getting successfully saved in my backend/controller folder on my local machine. Now i want to do prod deployment on Heroku but i dont know what path has to be set to save the file in production.

I have used 'fs' module to read and write file. Shown below.

```
fs.writeFileSync(
    path.resolve(__dirname, `${contractName} ${element.frequency}.docx`),
    buffer
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to use the "send(Buffer)" feature of express.

See the following page :

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send

```js
const contentTypes = {
    docx: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    pptx: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
    xlsx: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
};


res.set('Content-Type', contentTypes.docx);
res.send(buffer);
```

This is because the "fs" module is used to write the data on the disk, but if it is in production, most likely what you want is to let the user "download" a file, and that is done using `res.send()` which takes as an argument a Buffer to achieve this feature.